# Which method to use when making fruit powders?

Tags: fruit, dehydrating, powder

Searching online I found a lot of videos/ articles about making fruit powders, some of them dried the fruit itself then ground it. While other juiced the fruit, then ground it.

I am wondering which method will give me a better result regarding:

1) The taste;

2) The color.

The fruits that I am looking forward to try out: Mango, Orange, Lime, apple, grape, tomato, pepper and other fruits and veggies.

I will be using a cheap dehydrator if that is going to make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I tried drying lemon in a cheap dehydrator, and the flesh doesn't really dry well even when the skin /pith is hard and dry. The membranes of the flesh some too keep the moisture in.

For citrus at least, drying the juice/pulp would be worth a try, and is what I'll do next time I have some to try it on. I suggest drying the zest as well. The pulp or juice would have to be dried on something non-porous, like baking parchment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if you are going to dry the juice, would a normal tray work?

Answer (score -1):

The best method, and yet the most expensive one, is freeze drying the fruit, then pulverizing. Freeze drying is, as the name suggest, works by freezing the fruit and then reducing the pressure in the chamber the food is in... Eventually, the water in the food will sublimate leaving the rest of the fruit intact but completely dry.
And you'll even be preserving most of the aroma of the fruit.

So considering you might have access to a household-dryer; I would use that to dry the fruit; then pulverize.

Comment: The OP doesn't have access to freeze drying equipment, he specified that he is going to use a cheap dehydrator, and only asked about the difference between drying the whole fruit and the juice (or the pomace? he doesn't specify).

Comment: Oh I thought, I had added a section reagarding that, thanks for the comment. I'll update